# How to see full c# method declaration documentation in visual studio in tooltip?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

I've documented my function declaration like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// The summary blah blah blah
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg1">The first argument</param>
/// <param name="arg2">The second argument</param>
/// <returns>an integer</returns>
int MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2);
```

When I hover over the function in visual studio 2015 enterprise, the tooltip shows only the summary. I want to see the description for the arguments and return value, how can I see this?

Comment: Peek definition?

Answer (score 1):

The Parameter descriptions only appears when you are typing in arguments for that function. Just hovering over a pre-written method will only show the function Summary

Comment: Hmm, that's not very helpful when trying to read code. Alright

Comment: I agree, but I'm not the one who designed it

Comment: How about the return type, exception information, and remarks?